# Kernel data types u8, u16, u32, u64 not resolved

Tags: linux, kernel, headers

I am trying to compile some files related to wireless subsystem (mac80211) which use datatypes u8, u16, u32, u64. These are not resolved. The header file being referred to is linux/types.h which is included. However, __uxx data types are being recognized. I tried including the asm-generic/types.h but the problem doesn't get solved. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Strange – if it were user space, you'd need to use it with prefix `__` (e.g. `__u32`), but mac80211 is kernel related project.

Note: It does not matter whether you include `<linux/types.h>` or `<asm/types.h>` as the first includes the second. IMHO you should *not* include `<asm-generic/types.h>` (which is included by `<asm/types.h>`) due to portability.

See more info in [LDD](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf).